# Automatic button creation when activity gets passed a string and icon

Tags: java, android, button, automation

I was wondering how to automatically create a button when my activity gets passed a string and icon. I have an activity that is listening on a port to receive a string and image from a computer. Once this image and string get passed to my app, I want my app to automatically create a button using that image as the background and string as a label under the image.

I was wondering if someone could point me how to start since I am not even sure how to start this and am having issues finding solutions online.

I am also wondering how to position that new button at a specific location on my GUI. I want the new button to appear under another button I already have in my GUI

```
public void createButton (Bitmap bitmap, String applicationName, LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container){

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);

    RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_fragment);


    Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
    btn.setText(applicationName);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, app_row3_button3);
    btn.setLayoutParams(params);

    rLayout.addView(btn);




}
```

Here is my code so far... This is a method inside of a class that EXTENDS FRAGMENT (not activity). I am getting an error for "app_row3_button3", which is the ID of the button that I want my new button to be placed next to. This existing button already is defined previously in this class. My error is:

```
wrong 2nd argument type. found: 'android.widget.ImageButton', required: 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines and the location depends on the LinearLayout position, make sure the button is in this Linearlayout lin

```
ViewGroup linearLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lin);//lin is your linear layout id
        bt.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linearLayout.addView(bt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a button dynamically like this -

```
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setText("your_text_here");

   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);    
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, <first_button_id_here>);
    btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

And add that button to your `RelativeLayout` -

```
rLayout.addView(btn);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am working on creating my button now, for the <first_button_id_here>, it has to be an int type, so is this where I create the ID for my button, like button #1, will be "1" inserted into params.addRule? Then I assign my button the ID of "1" ? And also, the "rLayout" should be the ID of my layout that I want to add the button to? That is not working for me, and maybe it is because I am creating this button in a class that extends fragment, not activity.

Comment: `params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, <first_button_id_here>);` is for placing your newly created button below an existing button. You need to put your existing button id in place of `<first_button_id_here>`

Comment: I figured out the rLayout thing. But for the params.addRule, I get the error that I need to pass an integer into "first_button_id_here". I can't pass in the ID of my button widget that I want my new button to be created under.

Comment: You don't have id for your existing button? Is that dynamic too ?

Comment: I have an ID for my existing button, but I can not make it an integer, it tells me that an integer is an invalid ID for a button, and it has to start with a character. But I can only pass an integer into param.addRules

Comment: Paste your updated code and point out the exact line where you are getting error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110860/discussion-between-natalie-and-shadab-ansari).